# Check if I am on a slim (debian OS) image

Tags: debian, docker, slim

Suppose I run

```
docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint bash test-image
```

I know this is based on `debian:bullseye` but I have no other info about the image.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Is there a way (OS-wise) to check if this is a `slim` docker image of the full flavoured one?

e.g. perhaps check some packages which are NOT supposed to be found in a `slim` image?

Comment: since you can do anything to either image flavor (install or remove components), I'd honestly rather check for the capabilities you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really any way to guarantee which image you might have used. I routinely use the minimal [Network install](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) image for building systems and then add all the packages I want. Occasionally this may end up being a full graphical installation, but mostly it's a build that's suited to the target intended usage (along with my set of preferred utility packages).

You can use `dpkg` (or `dpkg-query`) to identify whether particular packages are installed. There may be better ways but this approach works for me:

```
dpkg -l 'rsync' | grep '^ii'    # Indication that 'rsync' is installed
dpkg -l 'ls*' | grep '^ii'      # List of matching installed packages
```

See `man dpkg-query` under the `--list` verb for more details

Comment: i'd use `grep ^.i` instead of `^ii` just in case the package is installed but held (which would be listed as `hi` rather than `ii`) or marked for removal (`ri`) or purging (`pi`) - an old habit from many years of piping dpkg -l / dlocate -l into `awk '/^.i/ { print $2 }'`...and i hold packages a lot (there are several that I only want to upgrade when I have time to deal with them properly, including firefox and chromium and kernel images/headers and various -dkms packages).